# Navigation Drawer, Toolbar, and Recycler View all in same xml layout file?

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I'm not good with android layout files and right now I have a file that has a Toolbar widget, and a recycler view widget. Here's the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/robot_chooser_toolbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
       android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
       android:elevation="4dp"
       android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
       app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/robot_recycler_view"
       android:paddingTop="5dp"
       android:scrollbars="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/robot_empty_view"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:textSize="20sp"
      android:text="@string/no_robots"
      android:elevation="3dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:visibility="gone"
      android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How could I add a DrawerLayout to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DrawerLayout has two parts

1. Main Content
2. Navigation Drawer

In other words, it contains two child views, in which one act as `MainContent` and other act as `Drawer`.
if you look at simple view

```
 <DrawerLayout>

   // VIEW 1 - MAIN CONTENT
    <RelativeLayout>

        //whatever you put in this, it will show in your main Content,
        // main Screen

    </RelativeLayout>

  //SECOND CHILD any view, it would be seen in your Side drawer

    <LinearLayout>

        //whatever you put inside, this will be seen on your drawerlayout

    </LinearLayout>
 </DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

---

In your case, suppose, you want to add fragment inside your `Drawer` then 
you can do as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/profileDrawer"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   android:id="@+id/robot_chooser_toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
   android:elevation="4dp"
   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
   app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
   android:id="@+id/robot_recycler_view"
   android:paddingTop="5dp"
   android:scrollbars="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/robot_empty_view"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:textSize="20sp"
  android:text="@string/no_robots"
  android:elevation="3dp"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:visibility="gone"
  android:gravity="center" />

 </LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="yourFragmentPackageName"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/drawer_fragment" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! What is the fragment part for at the bottom?

Comment: You can replace with anything. as i explained above, `DrawerLayout` has two child, so you can replace it with any `View` . in my example, i just added `Fragment` to explain, you can add any View.

Comment: Okay because what I am trying to add inside the navigation drawer are fragments. So when you click one of the 2 things in there, the view changes to the fragment

Comment: if you want to add fragment inside drawer, then the code i wrote, you can use it.

Comment: Okay. What I'm going for exactly is the recyclerview cards (cards are in a different layout file) and toolbar to been shown on start. Then with the nav drawer button press, or a swipe right the drawer open

Comment: that was not the question, the question was, how can you add `DrawerLayout`, which i explained and you can use. If you want to implement functionalities, you need to code. You cannot do in xml,`XML` is for structuring your UserInterface.

Comment: I would chat you but I do not have enough rep. How can I bring the fragment into view on click inside the drawer fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(??????, fragment).commit();

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions  - Read this. It has detailed information how can you do that.

Comment: I have read this a few times, the issue I'm having is not knowing what R.id to replace as the class with my navigation drawer is the main activity, not a fragment